# Modify excel file with formulas using javascript?

Tags: excel, cordova, excel-formula

Is it possible to modify an excel file using javascript and have fields with forumlas udpate accordingly.

I am doing a phonegap app where a lot of the business logic is already in the excel file. I am looking on keeping it there and use that as the engine. Alternative I am looking to write something in c++ and have a wrapper for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) there are some packages like this one ([node-xldx](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-xlsx)) that can read and edit excel documents.